# Integration by parts explanation

Tags: calculus, integration, integration-by-parts

I have he following question:
[image: Equation]

How did they get v prime to equal $x^n$ and they change v to be the integral of $x^n$

Comment: That's how partial integration works,you just pick $u$ and $v'$,what exactly is strange there?

Comment: @kingW3, actually it's only $u$ that's picked.  $v'$ is automatic.  Although to be fair some sources teach from the perspective of choosing $v'$ so that $u$ is automatic.  But I hate that.

Comment: but shouldnt my v prime be the differential of v which would be the $nx^n-1$

Comment: $v=\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}$ then $v'=x^n$.

Comment: @kingW3 yea I thought that v had to be equal $x^n$ and then i would find my v prime by differentiating that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do integration by parts, you only choose one thing:  $u$

After that, everything else is automatically determined.  When you choose $u$, then $v'$ is everything that's left over in the integrand.

For thoroughness I should mention that some sources teach that $v'$ should be picked as "the most readily integrable piece of the integrand" and therefore $u$ is automatically determined.  But I hate that approach because it's vague and there's actually a legitimate and very clear process for choosing $u$.

The [LIATE rule](https://math.berkeley.edu/~ehallman/math1B/IntByParts.pdf) is helpful for choosing $u$.  Applying that rule tells us to choose $u = \ln x$ for the given integral.

So:  $\displaystyle \int x^n \underbrace{\ln x}_u \, dx$

This means that $v'$ must be everything else remaining in the integrand: $\displaystyle \int \underbrace{x^n}_{v'} \underbrace{\ln x}_u \, dx$

Then to find $v$, you just integrate $v'$ using the power rule for integrals.  (By convention we ignore the arbitrary constant of integration when going from $v'$ to $v$ in integration by parts because it will always cancel out anyway.)

---

**Edit:** [Here's the official journal article](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2975556) about LIATE.  As of the time I post this you can read it for free if you register for a free JSTOR account.

Answer (score 2):

The so-called integration by parts formula comes from the chain rule of differentiation:
$$
(uv)' = u'v + uv'.
$$
By the definition of primitive we can write the above as
$$
uv + \text{constant} = \int u'v + \int uv',
$$
equivalent to
$$
\int uv' = uv - \int u'v  + \text{constant}.
$$
Now to apply this to a particular example like the present one $\int x^{n}\ln x$, it takes an observation to find out that taking $\ln x$ as $u$ and $x^{n}$ as $v$ is more convenient because $(\ln x)' = 1/x$ and $(\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1})' = x^{n}$ directly.

Answer (score 2):

They **chose** $\;u=\log x\;,\;\;v'=x^n\;$ , and then applied *exactly* the formula

$$\int x^n\log x\,dx=\overbrace{\frac{x^{n+1}\log}{n+1}}^{=uv}-\overbrace{\int\frac{x^{n+1}}{x(n+1)}dx}^{=\int u'v}=$$$${}$$

$$=\frac1{n+1}\left[x^{n+1}\log x-\int x^n\,dx\right]=\frac1{n+1}\left[x^{n+1}\log x-\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}\right]+C=$$

$$=\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}\left[\log x-\frac1{n+1}\right]+C$$

Comment: Okay i thought that my v prime was determined based on $x^n$ like how i choose my u to be equal log x i assumed i had to make my v equal $x^n$

Comment: @user2861799 It's *all* a simple choice. Now, that it'll work nicely or not is another matter. In this case it works pretty nicely, indeed.

Answer (score 2):

By comparing original integration with :

$$\int uv' ~~\text{and}~~  \int x^n \ln x$$

We get $v' = x^n , u = \ln x $

Now, $v'$ denotes derivative of $v$ ,

$$\frac{d{v}}{dx} = x^n \implies v = \int x^n dx$$

There is a priority rule for convenience of selecting $u$ :

$\text{ILATE}$ : Inverse Trig. > Logarithmic > Algebraic >Trigonometric Exponential >